# jQuery keep value of select option when new row is added

Tags: jquery

I have a form where I have a button to add rows with increment row id numbers. With new row I have remove button to remove newly added row. When the values entered  and add row is clicked then the values will be cleared in a new row and the previous values will be in the old row  It is working fine upto this. But in the form I have one dropdown values( select option ) when I am adding another row the values selected in the dropdown is clearing and not showing the previous selected values?
Here is the code for this

css:

```
.remove { display: none; }
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          var template = jQuery('#template');
          id = 0;
          jQuery('#addrow').click(function(){
            var row = jQuery(template).clone();
            template.find("input:text").val("");
            row.attr('id', 'row_' + (++id));
            row.find('.remove').show();
            template.before(row);
          });

          jQuery(document).on('click','.remove',function() {
            jQuery(this).closest('tr').remove();
          });

        });
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Option</th>
    <th>From Price</th>
    <th>To Price</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="template">
    <td>
      <select name="option" id="option">
        <option value="" selected>--select--</option>
        <option value="one">One</option>
        <option value="two">Two</option>
        <option value="three">Three</option>
        <option value="four">Four</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="from-price" id="from-price" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="to-price" id="to-price" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="remove" value="remove" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="addrow" value="+Add Row" />
```

So can someone tell me how to keep the values of dropdown in the old row when the new row is made?

Comment: From what I can see is the value is retained, it is actually adding a new row on top of the existing row. try adding multiple rows & check.

Comment: Only problem I could find is that the selected value from dropdown is not passed to the cloned new row, was this your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think this JS will do what you're asking for.

```
jQuery('#addrow').click(function(){
    var row = jQuery(template).clone();
    var templateSelectedIndex = template.find("select")[0].selectedIndex;
    template.find("input:text").val("");
    row.attr('id', 'row_' + (++id));
    row.find('.remove').show();
    row.find("select")[0].selectedIndex = templateSelectedIndex;
    template.before(row);
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e5ZBf/**

Note that I've avoided selecting your selectbox using ID, as you are duplicating it on the page with the same ID. This can lead to unexpected results. You ought to replace that `id="option"` with a class name. Same goes for other elements you're cloning.